# Django password_change view & PasswordChangeForm not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to get password_change view and PasswordChangeForm working, but I get an html where the form renders correctly but nothing happens when I fill the form and click enter and there isn't a "send" button for the form. I'm probably missing something simple here, but the docs doesn't seem very helpful.

So, this is the urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change
from sisacademico import views

    url(r'^password_changed/$', views.password_changed, name='password_changed'),

    url(r'^change_password/$', password_change,
            {'template_name': 'sisacademico/change_password.html',
             'post_change_redirect': sisacademico/password_changed/'}),
```

this is the html, change_password.html:

```
{% extends 'base_sisacademico.html' %}

{% block content %}

{{form.as_ul}}

{% endblock content %}
```

What I get is this form with no submit button that doesn't work[image]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django template form tags {{ form }} don't output a submit button. You're going to need to put that in your HTML. You'll have something like:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

take a look at the [form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/) for other examples